# Why is my LAN and DHCP conf "not a private class subnet"?

Tags: networking, dhcp, gateway, dhclient

I am maintaining a gateway server with a small LAN & wifi which acts as a firewall, backup server, broadband gateway, media server etc.

It was getting overcomplicated with Bind9 so I just de-installed it completely. Everything was running smoothly until I discovered I can't login to the backuppc admin site from any workstations - it only allows me in via localhost direct on the server. Apparently:

> it would appear you are attempting to access the BackupPC pages from outside your network (i.e. not on a private class subnet). By default the configuration for BackupPC prevents remote access to minimise the security risks of having your data widely available, but there are instances where this may not be desired

Here's my `dhcpd.conf`

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf
#
# Attention: If /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf exists, that will be used as
# configuration file instead of this file.

# Use this to send dhcp log messages to a different log file (you also
# have to hack syslog.conf to complete the redirection).
authoritative;
log-facility local7;
default-lease-time 7200;
max-lease-time 86400;
option domain-name "localdomain";
option domain-name-servers 208.67.220.220, 208.67.222.222;
ignore client-updates;
update-static-leases on;
update-optimization off;
ddns-update-style none;

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.0.5 192.168.0.254;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.0.3;
}
```

and this is what my laptop client's LAN and wifi interfaces look like:

```
adam@erebor:~$ ifconfig -a
enxd45d645c12ed: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.31  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::cb6a:9e79:1777:e285  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d4:5d:64:5c:12:ed  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 48070  bytes 37288002 (37.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 43659  bytes 9716286 (9.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1868  bytes 192244 (192.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1868  bytes 192244 (192.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.28  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::c5c5:4941:dff4:32f0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 34:e1:2d:c3:7c:51  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 305  bytes 38927 (38.9 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 283  bytes 47749 (47.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I expect I've got a basic error here but I can't see it.

===============================

Here's some IPv6 config stuff that I've got in the mix - I have been adding IPv6 config where it's given in the docs but it's definitely incomplete.

```
adam@gondolin:~$ cat /etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf 
default-lease-time 2592000;
preferred-lifetime 604800;
option dhcp-renewal-time 3600;
option dhcp-rebinding-time 7200;
allow leasequery;
option dhcp6.name-servers 3ffe:501:ffff:100:200:ff:fe00:3f3e;
option dhcp6.domain-search "test.example.com","example.com";
option dhcp6.info-refresh-time 21600;
```

I realise now that DNS is the default from the package.

I have some `iptables6` config as well, but that seems fine.

Comment: Could this be an IPv6 issue? Is there any way to retrieve the IP address of the client as seen by the BackupPC server?

Comment: Is this Ubuntu and if so what version?

Comment: No, the backuppc website doesn't log any access :( It's just a built-in CGI server and the logging is restricted to the backup & restore operations. As far as I can tell, I only have the option to disable this security check it does, but my concern is more about finding out what the configuration issue is.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 is the version